# (JS) How to delete the last element created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamic form where you can add text fields on the fly.
It works, but the problem is that the delete button I've implement clears the entire form, whereas I want it so just clear the last item created.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div id="Form1"></div>

<button type="button" onClick="createNode1()">+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="deleteNode1()">-</button>

<script>
function createNode1(){
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text"; 
input.placeholder = "Enter Text Here";
document.getElementById("Form1").appendChild(input); // put it into the DOM
}
//CLEARS THE FORM IF YOU MADE A MISTAKE
function deleteNode1(){
    var node = document.getElementById('Form1');
    while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
    }
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "the delete button I've implement" --> `while (node.hasChildNodes())` Interesting...

Comment: Why are you looping in the deletenode code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the while loop, it iterates and removes all childNodes as long as there's any left

```
function deleteNode1(){
    var node = document.getElementById('Form1');
    if (node.hasChildNodes())
         node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ra2s5r6z/1/)

Comment: Caution, if you click on [-] when #Form1 is empty, you get "Failed to execute 'removeChild'"

Answer (score 2):

As adeneo say or to avoid JS error if Form1 is empty, replace `while` with `if`:

```
function deleteNode1(){
    var node = document.getElementById('Form1');
    if(node.hasChildNodes()) {
        node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
    }
}
```